# reading github.com/username/kit/go/database/go/database/go.mod at revision go/database/v1.0.1: unknown revision go/database/v1.0.1

Tags: git, go, visual-studio-code, go-modules

I have a public kit repo which I pushed v1.0.3 on and has the following structure

```
go
-database
--database.go
--go.mod
--go.sum
```

And I require it with

```
require github.com/michael-ottink/kit/go/database v1.0.3
```

To test how a kit repo would work. But I get the following error when running `go mod tidy` in my main project

```
github.com/michael-ottink/kit/go/database@v1.0.3: reading github.com/michael-ottink/kit/go/database/go/database/go.mod at revision go/database/v1.0.2: unknown revision go/database/v1.0.3
```

I am new at this and I am struggeling to understand what the problem is ? If any more info is needed I'll update the post.

this is my database.go

```
package database

    import (
        "gorm.io/gorm"
    )
    
    type Database struct {
        *gorm.DB
    }
    
    type Config struct {
        Driver   string
        Host     string
        Username string
        Password string
        Port     string
        Database string
        Timezone string
    }
```

This error occurs if you try to require it into a entirely new project with only a go.mod , go.sum and main.go.

Comment: Can you show the content of `github.com/username/kit/go/database/go.mod`?

Comment: Code in your question and the link does not match. Can you please provide a reproducible example of the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/michael-ottink/kit

Comment: Try modify the line `module database` to `module github.com/michael-ottink/kit/go/database`

Comment: Pushed a new version with the module change and changed it in my mod file but I get the same error go: github.com/michael-ottink/kit/go/database@v1.0.3: reading github.com/michael-ottink/kit/go/database/go/database/go.mod at revision go/database/v1.0.3: unknown revision go/database/v1.0.3

Comment: I think your git config has issue. you need to use `ssh` in git config  rather than `https` i.e., `git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commit on `v1.0.3` added an empty module named `slice`. The repository became multi-modules and a few more rules are implied.
The documentation for a multi-modules repository is [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#faqs--multi-module-repositories).

Unfortunately, the first folder of the repository named `/kit` does not contain the modules but only its sub-folder `/go`.

When multiple modules are found, a tag like `v1.0.3` is attributed to the repository but there is no modules which means that
`go get github.com//michael-ottink/kit@v1.0.3` does not do anything.

When trying to go get the subfolder with `go get github.com//michael-ottink/kit/go@v1.0.3`, the returned error confirms that no module was found.

To go get the repo, tag could look like `go@v1.0.3`

To tag each module individually, tag could be `go/database/v1.0.3`. When the slice module is ready, it can be tagged similarly.

It remains that when starting with modules, one repository per module is a safer bet as quoted in the documentation ([here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26664#issuecomment-455232444)):

> For all but power users, you probably want to adopt the usual
> convention that one repo = one module. It's important for long-term
> evolution of code storage options that a repo can contain multiple
> modules, but it's almost certainly not something you want to do by
> default.