# go: github.com/myorg/myrepo@v0.0.4: reading github.com/myorg/myrepo/go.mod at revision v0.0.4: unknown revision v0.0.4

Tags: go, github, ssh, go-get

`go: github.com/myorg/myrepo@v0.0.4: reading github.com/myorg/myrepo/go.mod at revision v0.0.4: unknown revision v0.0.4`

I'm hitting the above blocker when `go mod tidy` inside a different private repo call it: `github.com/myorg/myrepo2` and attempting to fetch from my private repo `github.com/myorg/myrepo`

Contents of `github.com/myorg/myrepo` master branch go.mod (at the root project level)

```golang
module github.com/myorg/myrepo

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/abadojack/whatlanggo v1.0.1
    github.com/mmcdole/gofeed v1.1.3
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.3.0
)
```

The repo has in fact a tag / release named `v0.0.4`

Additionally, I've tried everything described in the following:

- https://golang.cafe/blog/how-to-fix-go-mod-unknown-revision.html
- [Installing private Go module: unknown revision error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609301/installing-private-go-module-unknown-revision-error/65609901#65609901)
- https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-modules

That is to say, I've tried configuring `~/.gitconfig`, `GOPRIVATE` and other env vars, `~/$HOME/.netrc`,and even generating a GitHub access token. I should note that I also have an SSH key associated with Github account on this machine and `~/.ssh/config` contents as below:

```sh
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed12345

Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

I also ruled out the submodule issue described here [reading github.com/username/kit/go/database/go/database/go.mod at revision go/database/v1.0.1: unknown revision go/database/v1.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893018/reading-github-com-username-kit-go-database-go-database-go-mod-at-revision-go-da)

I'm at a loss on this one so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If Go is accessing your private repository through HTTPS, then any SSH setting would not be used at all.
From your link, [this should have helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615480/6309) (after a [`go clean -modcache`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-clean-modcache)):

```
git config --global \
  url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf \
  "https://github.com"
go mod download
```

---

If you want to use/try SSH:

```
git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com:acme-corporation".insteadOf "https://github.com/acme-corporation"
```

(replace `acme-corporation` by your GitHub user account, assuming your private repository is not in an organization)
(check `ssh -Tv git@github.com` does authenticate as you)

Then `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'`: that way, you will see exactly what is considered during the SSH calls, and make sure your private key is indeed used.

---

The [OP j-diaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5842408/j-diaz) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254721/go-github-com-myorg-myrepov0-0-4-reading-github-com-myorg-myrepo-go-mod-at-re/70256375#comment124243102_70256375) an issue in their Git configuration:

> I ended up revising every entry in my `.gitconfig` file and ended up removing everything except the user entry and that made it work.
>
> ```
> [user] 
>   name = First Last 
>   email = email@exmaple.com
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up revising every entry in my `.gitconfig` file and ended up removing everything except the user entry and that made it work.

`
[user]
        name = First Last
        email = email@exmaple.com
`

Comment: @j-diaz Perfect. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.